# Maven pass build with up to X tests failing

Tags: maven, testing

Is there a way to allow some tests to fail in a build, so that the build still passes if up to X tests fail?

i.e. mvn -DmaxFailures=19 test

Would FAIL iff greater than 20 tests fail, while pass iff only 19 or fewer failed.

Comment: Either all tests run correct or not. You can skip all tests but not only a few of them. Furthermore that sounds more like problems with environments which is in indicator for running integration tests instead of unit tests.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do this with a custom plugin, or else using a scripting plugin in place of a custom plugin (ideally you want to switch to a custom plugin at some point though)

What you want to do is really "borrow" the [`failsafe:verify`](http://maven.apache.org/surefire/maven-failsafe-plugin/xref/org/apache/maven/plugin/failsafe/VerifyMojo.html) mojo's logic and from the parsed `TEST-*.xml` files count up the number of test failures and fail the build if above your threshold.